# Flutterでのイベント発火方法を知りたいです

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutterで画面遷移をした後に、遷移先の画面でFirestoreからデータを読みだして表示させたいのですが、画面が作られた後すぐに勝手に発火するイベントを調べても見つけることができません。onPressedで発火させてFirestoreの方から読み出しをすることはできているので、自然発火するイベントを教えてもらいたいです。

Answer (score 0):

まずStatefulWigetを使います：

```
    class Youclass extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _Youclass();
    }
    class _Youclass extends State<TvMain> {
    @override
    void initState() {
        Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then((_) async {
          // ロード処理を行う: Firestoreとか
          ....
           setState((){});
        });
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
           // return あなたのWiget
    　　　}
    }
```

こんな感じでページが切り替えた時の対応を入れることができます。